# Local NodeJS app cannot establish connection to a PostgresDB docker container

Tags: node.js, postgresql, docker, database-connection

I'm developing a NodeJS/Express application which need to exchange information with a Postgres database for my Cybersecurity exam; both the Node app and the Postgres database will be living in a docker container for them self using docker compose and a common network to exchange data.

**The problem:** Seems I cannot manage to establish a connection with the npm `PG` client (Vers. 8+) to the database hosted on the docker container.  Each time I run the connection procedure from a JS file I get the following error:

```shell
node .\test.mjs
connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:5432
```

**The testing environment:** for now I'm trying to establish a connection from a test Node app on my local machine with the local installation of NodeJS, meanwhile the docker container holds the database built with a compose file(Docker is being executed on the same machine).

The `test.mjs` for connection testing:

```mjs
import pg from "pg";

const client = new pg.Client({
  user: "db_root",
  password: "root",
  host: "localhost",
  port: 5432,
});

client
  .connect()
  .then(() => {
    console.log("[INFO]: DB CONNECTION SUCCESSFUL");
    client.query("SELECT NOW()").then((res) => {
      console.log(res.rows);
      client.end();
    });
  })
  .catch((err) => {
    console.log("[ERROR] " + err);
  });
```

This is the docker compose file which builds the database, there are few scripts SQL in a folder called `db` which are executed during the building of the container, they are used to create some tables, user with privileges and access to some tables and some table population scripts.

```
version: "3.9"

services:
  frontend:
    build: .
    container_name: node-server
    restart: unless-stopped
    depends_on:
      - database
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
      - "3443:3443"
    networks:
      - my-net
  database:
    image: postgres:latest
    container_name: postgredb
    restart: unless-stopped
    networks:
      - my-net
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_USER=db_root
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=root
      - POSTGRES_DB=securedb
    expose:
      - 5432
    volumes:
      - ./db:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d
  admin:
    image: adminer
    restart: unless-stopped
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
    networks:
      - my-net
networks:
  my-net:
    driver: bridge
```

This is the docker container log:

```shell
postgredb  | The files belonging to this database system will be owned by user "postgres".
postgredb  | This user must also own the server process.
postgredb  | 
postgredb  | The database cluster will be initialized with locale "en_US.utf8".
postgredb  | The default database encoding has accordingly been set to "UTF8".
postgredb  | The default text search configuration will be set to "english".
postgredb  | 
postgredb  | Data page checksums are disabled.
postgredb  | 
postgredb  | fixing permissions on existing directory /var/lib/postgresql/data ... ok
postgredb  | creating subdirectories ... ok
postgredb  | selecting dynamic shared memory implementation ... posix
postgredb  | selecting default max_connections ... 100
postgredb  | selecting default shared_buffers ... 128MB
postgredb  | selecting default time zone ... Etc/UTC
postgredb  | creating configuration files ... ok
postgredb  | running bootstrap script ... ok
postgredb  | performing post-bootstrap initialization ... ok
postgredb  | initdb: warning: enabling "trust" authentication for local connections
postgredb  | You can change this by editing pg_hba.conf or using the option -A, or
postgredb  | --auth-local and --auth-host, the next time you run initdb.
postgredb  | syncing data to disk ... ok
postgredb  | 
postgredb  | 
postgredb  | Success. You can now start the database server using:
postgredb  | 
postgredb  |     pg_ctl -D /var/lib/postgresql/data -l logfile start
postgredb  | 
postgredb  | waiting for server to start....2022-05-25 15:24:12.850 UTC [48] LOG:  starting PostgreSQL 14.3 (Debian 14.3-1.pgdg110+1) on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (Debian 10.2.1-6) 10.2.1 20210110, 64-bit
postgredb  | 2022-05-25 15:24:12.853 UTC [48] LOG:  listening on Unix socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"
postgredb  | 2022-05-25 15:24:12.862 UTC [49] LOG:  database system was shut down at 2022-05-25 15:24:12 UTC
postgredb  | 2022-05-25 15:24:12.867 UTC [48] LOG:  database system is ready to accept connections
postgredb  |  done
postgredb  | server started
postgredb  | CREATE DATABASE
postgredb  | 
postgredb  | 
postgredb  | /usr/local/bin/docker-entrypoint.sh: running /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/createTable.sql
postgredb  | CREATE TABLE
postgredb  | CREATE TABLE
postgredb  | CREATE TABLE
postgredb  | 
postgredb  | 
postgredb  | /usr/local/bin/docker-entrypoint.sh: running /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/createUser.sql
postgredb  | CREATE ROLE
postgredb  | CREATE ROLE
postgredb  | GRANT
postgredb  | GRANT
postgredb  | GRANT
postgredb  | GRANT
postgredb  | GRANT
postgredb  | GRANT
postgredb  | 
postgredb  | 
postgredb  | /usr/local/bin/docker-entrypoint.sh: running /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/populateTable.sql
postgredb  | INSERT 0 1
postgredb  | INSERT 0 1
postgredb  | INSERT 0 1
postgredb  | INSERT 0 1
postgredb  | INSERT 0 1
postgredb  | INSERT 0 1
postgredb  | INSERT 0 1
postgredb  | INSERT 0 1
postgredb  | INSERT 0 1
postgredb  | INSERT 0 1
postgredb  | 
postgredb  | 
postgredb  | /usr/local/bin/docker-entrypoint.sh: running /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/setTimezone.sql
postgredb  | SET
postgredb  | 
postgredb  | 
postgredb  | 2022-05-25 15:24:13.317 UTC [48] LOG:  received fast shutdown request
postgredb  | waiting for server to shut down....2022-05-25 15:24:13.321 UTC [48] LOG:  aborting any active transactions
postgredb  | 2022-05-25 15:24:13.322 UTC [48] LOG:  background worker "logical replication launcher" (PID 55) exited with exit code 1
postgredb  | 2022-05-25 15:24:13.322 UTC [50] LOG:  shutting down
postgredb  | 2022-05-25 15:24:13.358 UTC [48] LOG:  database system is shut down
postgredb  |  done
postgredb  | server stopped
postgredb  | 
postgredb  | PostgreSQL init process complete; ready for start up.
postgredb  | 
postgredb  | 2022-05-25 15:24:13.435 UTC [1] LOG:  starting PostgreSQL 14.3 (Debian 14.3-1.pgdg110+1) on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (Debian 10.2.1-6) 10.2.1 20210110, 64-bit
postgredb  | 2022-05-25 15:24:13.435 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on IPv4 address "0.0.0.0", port 5432
postgredb  | 2022-05-25 15:24:13.435 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on IPv6 address "::", port 5432
postgredb  | 2022-05-25 15:24:13.440 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on Unix socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"
postgredb  | 2022-05-25 15:24:13.446 UTC [70] LOG:  database system was shut down at 2022-05-25 15:24:13 UTC
postgredb  | 2022-05-25 15:24:13.451 UTC [1] LOG:  database system is ready to accept connections
```

Since I also have a container with Adminer I tested all my user and root logins using the browser GUI and it can make connections fine , with the only difference that I don't use localhost for Adminer but the container name for host field since they are on two different docker container within the same network, but at least I know that is not a "password"/"user" misspelling or problem with SQL scripts at least.

**Started from scratch:** Since I could not understand where the problem could reside I tried to start from Zero, I've created an empty folder somewhere else on my machine, created a new docker compose and `index.js` file for testing , installed only the module `pg` with NPM, built the container from compose and the connection from a node local machine works( and it angers me much).

The `index.js`:

```javascript
const pg = require("pg");

const client = new pg.Client({
  user: "admin",
  password: "password",
  database: "mydb",
  port: 5432,
  host: "localhost",
});

client
  .connect()
  .then(() => {
    console.log("Connected to database");
    client.query("SELECT NOW()", (err, res) => {
      console.log(res.rows);
      client.end();
      if (err) {
        console.log(err);
      }
    });
  })
  .catch((err) => {
    console.log(err);
  });
```

Docker compose file:

```plaintext
version: "3.9"

services:
  database:
    image: "postgres:latest"
    container_name: postgresdatabase
    ports:
      - 5432:5432
    restart: unless-stopped

    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: admin
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: password
      POSTGRES_DB: mydb
    volumes:
      - ./user.sql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/user.sql
    networks:
      - default

  node:
    build: .
    container_name: node
    ports:
      - 3000:3000
    depends_on:
      - database
    networks:
      - default

networks:
  default:
    driver: bridge
```

Shell result:

```shell
node .\index.js
Connected to database
[ { now: 2022-05-25T16:21:44.591Z } ]
```